# What should one do when in a programming language dispute two programmers cannot converge to a common point?

Tags: discussion

I entered a [very long discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521206/arm-neon-how-to-convert-from-uint8x16-t-to-uint8x8x2-t#comment74111636_43521206) with an experienced user, and I am pretty sure I have provided enough arguments to support my case, but it seems I only manage to annoy him. I am under the impression he is not listening to me, because I do not have enough reputation. Can somebody take a look and solve the dispute?

I assume this question as it is would be difficult to respond, so I ask more generally: What should one do when two programmers in a programming language dispute cannot converge to a common point?

Comment: It should have asked one or both of you to take the discussion to chat long before it got to that length.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I would delete everything once an agreement is reached, but by moving it to private chat wouldn't allow others to intervene to solve the dispute.

Comment: Always avoid getting into a discussion with Olaf.  Flag a moderator to get rid of the noise, no need to keep anything by the looks of it.

Comment: I do not think your rep here has anything to do with it.  The person *knows* its bad so you are not going to change their mind.  Best thing to do is walk away and let others have a got at it.  Also if you move the discussion to chat using the link under the comments everyone will be able to see that chat room and enter it.

Comment: Welcome to the world of C++ pedantry. Our anal-retentiveness levels are over 9000.

Comment: Do you want someone to help resolve the disagreement about C++ or about whether the question is on-topic? Someone here can probably help with the latter, but I am not sure anyone wants to help with the former! `:-)`

Comment: The only solution is to stop writing C++.

Comment: I saw a similar situation recently and it was clear that I was just going to have to agree to disagree, but the other party refused to let it go.   I found that posting "Thanks, have a nice day" works to allow both parties to just move on.  But it seems like you want to actually win this debate, and sometimes that is just not possible.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't really think stooping to the level of personal attacks is called for, Hans.

Comment: What makes you think anything needs to be done about it in the first place? You're asking what you should do when someone disagrees with you, but that question is beyond the scope of this site and was probably taught in elementary school.

Comment: Hmm, no, that was not a personal attack, merely advice.  I'll assume that was not a personal attack either, keeps it all nice and friendly.

Comment: uh-oh. Somebody's wrong on the internet. Not gonna get any sleep tonight!  :-)

Comment: @HansPassant - first rule of Frozen: Nobody Messes With The Snowman! NOBODY!!!!! :-)

Comment: @Will: but...but...but...isn't C++ [the one, true programming language of which all others are but Shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages)?

Comment: It's not unusual for a certain subset of C++ programmers to obsess over an ideal notion of "portability". This frequently misses the point. *True* portability is often unattainable, or at least not reasonably (read: cost-effectively). And plenty of code that is written doesn't even have portability as a goal. That certainly seems to be true in your case—you're clearly targeting the ARM Neon and using types that are already proprietary to compilers targeting that architecture, making portability a pointless academic debate. What do you do? Ignore and move on. If you do care, ask a new question.

Comment: @Antonio There are no private chat rooms on SO for normal users. Anyone can join a chat room for the two of you and help discuss something.

Comment: You are allowed to walk away from your computer.  It's not compulsory to correct everyone who's wrong on the Internet.

Comment: The concept of _undefined behavior_ in C and C++ always amuses me. If you know your compiler you often have a pretty good idea of what will happen even if you invoke the dreaded _undefined behavior_. The pointer is uninitialized and dereferencing it will perhaps segfault or just return a garbage value. But uh, oh not in the world of C and C++... It will invoke __undefined behavior__ which most likely will cause your computer to emit toxic fumes or perhaps grow wings or at least format the hard disk. You never know except that the effect will be dramatic...

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Nothing needs to happen here.

In your specific case your question is not on hold and the other user has stopped posting comments. There is no problem that someone needs to take action on.

> What should one do when two programmers in a programming language
>   dispute cannot converge to a common point?

If you really want to carry on an extended discussion, take it to chat. But otherwise the same answer applies: Nothing. There are over 700K users on this site. Occasionally someone is going to disagree with you. As long as the only thing they're doing is disagreeing the community does not need to intervene.

If the other user starts an edit war, vandalizing posts, or posting rude comments, then you can flag for moderator attention. You can also flag to clean up the comments if the discussion just got too long and now it's a mess.

Comment: If two parties want to have it out over some C++ question, they can come to the Lounge. The party that is wrong will be appropriately flamed, out-pedanted, and humiliated.

Comment: If two parties want to have it out over some C question, they can come to the Lounge. Then *both* parties will be appropriately flamed, out-pedanted, and humiliated.

Comment: @Mysticial: I now wonder which party is "wrong" in this case...

Comment: @user000001 You should stop doing that.

Comment: @MrLister: doing what?

Comment: @user000001 Wonder which party is wrong in a discussion about a library you only just now heard of!

Comment: Clearly you've forgotten about [our duty](https://xkcd.com/386/).

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Hence the use of the C++ Lounge, so the pedants can tag-team the wrong parties and still get some sleep between shifts.

Comment: @Mystical Looking forward to next time! :)

Answer (score 5):

Unless the question is affecting a piece of code that I am working on, I see only two reasonable approaches for dealing with such an issue.  The first is to walk away.  The second is to run.  Furthermore, if there is a dispute over how a specific set of code will be interpreted, I prefer to restate it using a syntax that is not being disputed.